# Back up all SQL databases to storage blob container

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am currently trying to figure out how to backup all databases to a blob container in Azure, I have successfully done it for one database, but not sure how to select all and excluding the system databases.

```
DECLARE @filename varchar(500)
DECLARE @dbname varchar(500)
DECLARE @url varchar(500)
DECLARE @subfolder varchar(500)
DECLARE @date nvarchar(256)

SET @date = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(256),GetDate(), 120),':','-'),' ', '-');

SELECT @dbname = 'db1'
SELECT @url = 'https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/sql-migration-data/'
SELECT @subfolder = @dbname + '/'
SELECT @date

SET @filename = @url + @subfolder + @dbname + '_diff_' + @date + '.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE [db1] TO  URL = @filename WITH  DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db1-Differential Database Backup', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: *Loop* through the databases, excluded any with a Database ID <= 4

Comment: Instead of trying to write the script yourself, use [Ola Halengren's backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) and specify `USER_DATABASES` in the `databases` parameter. The URL is passed through the URL parameter

Comment: The doc page contains examples that show you to backup to Azure, use credentials, compression, etc. Compression is always beneficial, especially when sending the backup to remote storage

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do this yourself. Most DBAs use [Ola Hallengren's backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). You can specify multiple databases by name, pattern or just specify `USER_DATABASES` or `SYSTEM_DATABASES`.

To backup to Azure, all you need is to pass the target URL. From the documentation example

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@URL = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer',
@Credential = 'MyCredential',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@Verify = 'Y'
```

@Compress and @Verify should be used every time. For starters, you don't want to keep a *bad* backup. Compression improves backup speed even when storing to a local disk. It's much more important when uploading the data to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor to loop through sys.databases , if id is greater than 4 execute your backup instructions.

```sql
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 4

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    ...
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
GO
```

It will execute till the fetch of database in successfull using `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`

you can execute

```sql
    SELECT @subfolder = @dbname + '/'
    SET @filename = @url + @subfolder + @dbname + '_diff_' + @date + '.bak'
    SET @backupCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] TO  URL = ''' + @filename + ''' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N''' + @dbname + '-Differential Database Backup'', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'
    
    EXEC(@backupCommand)
```

Comment: FYI, syntax like `N'...[' + @dbname + ']...'` is *not* injection safe.

Comment: yes that's true! however I think in this particular context , risk is negligible.

Comment: You don't even need dynamic SQL, you can parameterize `BACKUP DATABASE @dbname` directly

Comment: I'm not sure how you write this, I am only testing at the moment, but needs to be rolled out to production at some point.

Comment: can execute second part of code between begin and fetch next...